# Why is writing beans to CSV not working after OpenCSV upgrade from 4.1 to 5.7.1

Tags: java, csv, serialization, opencsv

I'm using [OpenCSV](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#general) to write Java beans to CSV file. Here's the code snippet:

```
  public void generateCSVFile(List<?> domains, String[] columns, String fileName) {
    try {
    final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
    CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer);
    csvWriter.writeNext(columns);
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(domains)) {
        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy mappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
        mappingStrategy.setType(Class.forName(domains.get(0).getClass().getTypeName()));
        mappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
        StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<?> builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(
                csvWriter);
        StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter = builder.withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy).build();
        beanWriter.write(domains);
        csvWriter.close();
        writer.close();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       LOG.error("Exception occured while generating CSV file : {}", e)
     }
}
```

This was working fine with opencsv version 4.1. This has generated a CSV file with headers and columns in the order I've passed the columns(String[]). Recently, I've updated the version to 5.7.1, after which it's generating a CSV file only with header and not the data. It generates an empty file, with only header present in the generated file.

I've tried using `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy`. It's generating the file with data, but in the ascending order of the attributes and with attributes in Uppercase, as it's the default behavior.

Is there a way to get `ColumnPositionMappingStrategy` work with version 5.7.1, like it worked in version 4.1?

Comment: You sure that `domains` is not empty?

Comment: Yes. domains list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work with both OpenCSV versions, 4.1 and 5.7:

### Serialization

```
public static <T> void writeToCSV(String location, Class<T> type, List<T> records, String[] columns)
          throws IOException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException {

    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<T> mappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
    mappingStrategy.setType(type);
    mappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
    try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(location)) {
      StatefulBeanToCsv<T> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<T>(writer)
                      .withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy)
                      .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                      .build();
      beanToCsv.write(records);
    }
}
```

### Usage example

```
String[] columns = new String[]{"a", "b"};
List<Bean> objects = List.of(new Bean("A1", "B1"),
                             new Bean("A2", "B2"));
String location = "beans.csv";

try {
    CSVUtils.writeToCSV(location, Bean.class, objects, columns);
} catch (IOException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException | CsvDataTypeMismatchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Given that the class `Bean` has two String attributes `a` and `b`.

I tested the above with Java 8, 11 and 17.